# Similarities Between Mechanical Engineering and Computer Engineering

Tags: mechanical-engineering, computer-engineering, software, computer-aided-design

Im a high school student and I am writing an essay regarding my passion in various subjects of science, i chose engineering. I love learning about computers and coding etc and I'm also a great fan of mechanical engineering, the designing, the mechanical works involved, fluids etc..

This makes me think, what are the similarities (theoretical and practical) between these two fields? Knowing this would also help me summarize my interests in these fields in simple and concise manner.

Comment: This is asking for opinions which will get closed. However: logic. Any engineering problem has to have a logical approach, any software code needs a logical approach.

Comment: @SolarMike I see, where should i ask this question then?

Comment: There are common points. Some principles emphasized in programming (from CS), like encapsulation, reuse, (arguably) strict functionality are ones I like. A way of thinking that elevates those principles to first-class importance fits nicely into a methodical design and analysis of, say, electro-mechanical systems or fluid systems. Another common point can be leveraging a strong mathematical foundation. But there is simply too much varied detail in the practicum of each field for one person to cover them all. I don't think you can avoid this by searching for some unifying principle as the "key"

Answer (score 2):

Mechanical Engineering uses physical properaties of materials & engineering physics to solve problems. The major elements are Materials, Thermal, Fluids, & Static and Dynamic Design & Analysis. Electrical and control is limited to basic circuits and the control of processes.

Computer Engineering combines Electrical Engineering & Computer Science to design computers, computer components and software.

They are the same in that they are both engineering disciplines, but after Math (some of it), Physics, & Chemistry, I doubt any of the undergraduate classes would be the same.